# Proving that a sequence converges

Tags: real-analysis, limsup-and-liminf

This is what I've tried:

(a) Using mathematical induction, I can show that $b_{i+1}$ is smaller than $b_i$.
Therefore, $b_i$ is monotonically decreasing.
Then, I thought it's kind of obvious that $b_i$ is bounded because $\{a_i\}$ is a bounded sequence in $\mathbb{R}$.
Is this correct?

(b) Since $b_i$ converges, I can say $\lim _{i\to \infty} b_i  = p$ for some $p \in\mathbb{R}$. And this $p$ will equal to $\sup a_k$ when $k$ is large enough.
Hence, by definition, (b) is proven. Is this correct?

Thank you so much!

[image]

*I added the definition of lim sup below.

[image]

+Theorem 3.17
[image]

Comment: What is your definition of $\limsup$?

Comment: @Peter Tamaroff If follows the definition of lim sup in Rudin. I've attached the image.

Comment: Of course it will follow, but the proof is not something obvious.

Comment: @Peter Tamaroff Oh I meant that the definition is from Rudin. I didn't mean the proof follows just from the definition!

Comment: My question is: which definition of the $\limsup$ are you given to use in order to solve $(b)$? It clearly can't be the one in Wikipedia. Do you want to solve it with Rudin's definition?

Comment: @PeterTamaroff Yes! I want to solve it with Rudin's definition!

Comment: Is it my browser or all these pictures are dead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're defining $$\ell^*=\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}s_n$$ as the greatest upper bound of all subsequential limits of $\langle s_n\rangle$. We want to prove that, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n=\ell^*$.

First, we show

> **LEMMA1** Let $\langle s_n\rangle$ be a sequence. Then there exists a subsequence $n_k$ such that $$\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}s_{n_k}=\ell^*=\sup S$$ where $S=\{x:x\text{ is a subsequential limit of }s_n\}$.

**P** If $\ell^*=+\infty$ then the sequence is unbounded and we can obtain a sequence $n_k$ such that $s_{n_k}>k$ and the claim is true. Now suppose the sequence is bounded. Then $\ell^*$ exists finitely. By definition, given $N>0$ there exists $x\in S$ such that $$x \leq \ell^*<x+\frac 1{2N}$$

Thus $0 \leq x-\ell^*<\dfrac 1{2N}$ so we can say $|x-\ell^*|<\dfrac 1{2N}$. Let $j_k$ be such that $$s_{j_k}\to x$$

Then there exists $M=M_N$ such that implies $$|s_{j_M}-x|< \dfrac 1{2N}$$

But then $$\left| {{\ell ^*} - {s_{{j_M}}}} \right| \leqslant \left| {{\ell ^*} - x} \right| + \left| {x - {s_{{j_M}}}} \right| < \frac{1}{2N} + \frac{1}{2N} = \frac 1N$$

Now let $N$ vary throughout $1,2,\ldots$. We construct a sequence $M_1,M_2,\ldots$ as follows. Let $M_1$ be the number promised such that $$\left| {\ell ^*} - s_{m_{1,M_1}} \right| \leqslant 1$$ where $s_{m_{1,k}}\to x_1$ for some $x_1\in S$ as before. Now let $M_2$ be first number such that $m_{2,M_2}>m_{1,M_1}$ and $$\left| {{\ell ^*} - {s_{{m_{{2,M_2}}}}}} \right| \leqslant \frac{1}{2}$$ where $s_{m_{2,k}}\to x_2$ for some $x_2\in S$. Continue like this: we obtain a sequence $n_k=m_{k,M_k}$ such that $$\left| {{\ell ^*} - {s_{{n_k}}}} \right| \leqslant \frac{1}{k}$$ which means $$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{k \to \infty } {s_{{n_k}}} = {\ell ^*}$$ $\hspace{15.5 cm} \blacktriangle$

By the same token, we can show

> **LEMMA2** There exists a subsequence such that $s_{m_k}\to \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n$. I leave the proof to you, since it is very similar to the above.

---

Now all is clear to prove

> **PROP** Let $\langle s_n\rangle $ be a sequence. Define $x_n=\sup\limits_{k\geq n}\{s_k\}$ and$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n=\ell$. Then $\ell=\ell^*$

**P** By the previous **LEMMA** there exist subsequences such that $$\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}s_{n_k}=\ell^*\\ \lim\limits_{j\to\infty}s_{m_j}=\ell$$

By definition of $\ell^*$, we must have $\ell\leq \ell^*$. It remains to show $\ell^*\leq \ell$.  Pick $n>0$. By the very definition of the $\langle x_n\rangle $ we must have $$x_n\geq s_k$$ for each $k\geq n$. In particular $$x_n\geq s_{n_j}$$ for each $n_j>n$. This means that $$x_n\geq \ell^*$$

Since $n$ was arbitrary, $x_n\geq \ell^*$ for each $n$, so $\ell\geq \ell^*$ $\hspace{15.5 cm} \blacktriangle$

Comment: Hi! Your first Lemma equals to 3.17 Theorem in Rudin, right? (I would attached 3.17 Theorem image). And I'm not sure about what your second Lemma means. $\lim _{n\to \infty} x_n$ is equal to sup s$_k$?

Comment: I mean that there is a subsequence that converges to the same limit $x_n$ converges to.

Comment: Is the 2nd one of Proposition 15 (page 9 of http://www.math.upenn.edu/~trietle/teaching/math360/notes/week3.pdf) equal to Lemma 2 in your proof?

Comment: @InfimumMaximum Yes.

Answer (score 3):

(a) You are right, you can formalise your second sentence by applying the [monotone convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem).

(b) As you point out, this follows just from the [definition of the limit superior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior) and of $\{b_n\}$,

$$\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n:=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\sup_{m\geq n}a_m\right)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} b_n.$$

EDIT 2: In what follows I am assuming that $(*)$ is finite. However, if $(*)=+\infty$ then one can re-do the proof by following the same steps.

EDIT: We can show that both definitions are equivalent, that is

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\sup_{m\geq n}a_m\right)=\sup\{x:\exists\{a_{n_k}\}\subseteq\{a_n\},a_{n_k}\rightarrow x\text{ as }k\rightarrow\infty\},\quad\quad (*)$$

simply by using the triangle inequality and the definitions of the supremum of a set and the limit of a sequence. We do this in two steps:

---

By the definition of the supremum, we have that

$$\sup\{x:\exists\{a_{n_k}\}\subseteq\{a_n\},a_{n_k}\rightarrow x\text{ as }k\rightarrow\infty\}=p$$

implies that for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists a subsequence $\{a_{n_k}\}$ of $\{a_n\}$ such that

$$\left|\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}a_{n_k}-p\right|\leq \varepsilon.$$

By the definition of limit, we have that there exists a $K$ such that

$$\left|a_{n_k}-\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}a_{n_k}\right|\leq \varepsilon,$$

for all $k\geq K$. In particular, we have that for every $n\geq0$ we can find an $N$ (just pick any in $\{n_k\geq n:k\geq K\}$) such that

$$\left|a_{N}-p\right|= \left|a_{N}-\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}a_{n_k}+\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}a_{n_k}-p\right| =\left|a_{N}-\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}a_{n_k}\right|+\left|\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}a_{n_k}-p\right|\leq2\varepsilon$$

So, for any $n$, pick the corresponding $N$ as above, and we have that

$$\sup_{m\geq n}a_m\geq a_N\geq p-2\varepsilon.$$

Since the $\varepsilon$ was arbitrary we have that for any $n$, $\sup_{m\geq n}a_m\geq p$. Hence,

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\sup_{m\geq n}a_m\right)\geq p=\sup\{x:\exists\{a_{n_k}\}\subseteq\{a_n\},a_{n_k}\rightarrow x\text{ as }k\rightarrow\infty\}.$$

---

We can establish the other inequality in a very similar fashion. Let

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\sup_{m\geq n}a_m\right)=q.$$

Then, for each $k>0$ we can find an $m_k$ such that

$$\left|\sup_{m\geq m_k}a_m-q\right|\leq \frac{1}{2k}.$$

Similarly, we can find an $n_k\geq m_k$ such that

$$\left|a_{n_k}-\sup_{m\geq m_k}a_m\right|\leq\frac{1}{2k}.$$

So,

$$\left|a_{n_k}-q\right|\leq \left|a_{n_k}-\sup_{m\geq m_k}a_m+\sup_{m\geq m_k}a_m-q\right|\leq \left|a_{n_k}-\sup_{m\geq m_k}a_m\right|+\left|\sup_{m\geq m_k}a_m-q\right|\leq \frac{1}{k}. $$

Hence, we have constructed a subsequence $\{a_{n_k}\}$ such that $a_{n_k}\rightarrow q$ as $k\rightarrow\infty$. Thus,

$$\sup\{x:\exists\{a_{n_k}\}\subseteq\{a_n\},a_{n_k}\rightarrow x\text{ as }k\rightarrow\infty\}\geq q =\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\sup_{m\geq n}a_m\right).$$

Putting together both inequalities we get $(*)$.

Comment: What if the OP has been given **another** definition of the $\limsup$? It would be dumb to give this exercise if one has already defined the limit superior to be that!

Comment: @PeterTamaroff Well, if the OP adds it to the question I'll adjust the answer accordingly.

Comment: Upvoted accordingly! I will let you know if I find any things to correct, and I would appreciate if you do the same with my answer.

Comment: InfimumMaximum see edit, @PeterTamaroff that was considerably more long-winded that I hoped it'd be!

Comment: Are you saying the proof I give is long winded? Or your proof? Or both? =P

Comment: @PeterTamaroff ^^ - well I was referring to mine, but now that you mention it... To be fair I haven't even considered the case that the limit might be $+\infty$ (><) which you did.

Comment: Ah... but that case is easy! =) I like the proof you give.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff cheers.

Comment: @jkn Hi, you wrote, "if (∗)=+∞ then one can re-do the proof by following the same steps" but we can't set sup value as p anymore so I think we can't follow the same steps! Can i just say if they one of them is +∞, the other should be also +∞?

Comment: "but we can't set sup value as p anymore" -- you are right, you need to use the appropriate definitions for what it means for $\sup A=+\infty$ (that is, that for every $N\geq 0$ we can find an $x\in A$ such that $x\geq N$) and $\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty} a_n=+\infty$ (that is, that for every $N\geq 0$ we can find an $n$ such that $a_m\geq N$ for all $m\geq n$). However, the remainder of the proof is quite similar. For the first direction you need to show that for any $M$ and $n$ we can find an $N\geq n$ such that $a_N\geq M$.

Comment: For the second direction, you need to construct a subsequence $\{a_{n_k}\}$ such that for every $N\geq0$ there exists a $K$ such that $a_{n_k}\geq N$ for all $k\geq K$. Give it go! "Can i just say if they one of them is +∞, the other should be also +∞?" -- unfortunately no, [there is no such thing as a free lunch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There_ain't_no_such_thing_as_a_free_lunch) :).

Comment: By the way [this](http://unow.nottingham.ac.uk/resources/resource.aspx?hid=c6c045f6-286d-6b9f-b96c-36a998632fc3) is a rather nice course that I worked through while doing the first few chapters of Rudin -- it provided me with some "intuition" with regards to the material discussed in the book and let me see someone else doing proofs which can was very helpful to me since I had little experience in proving statements at the time -- you might like to check it out.

Comment: @jkn Wait! {a_n} is a bounded sequence so lim sup always exists(its finite). Isn't it? (page 4 of http://www.math.upenn.edu/~trietle/teaching/math360/notes/week3.pdf)

Comment: Yes! You're right. So all the infinity discussion was irrelevant -_-. However, you can still prove the statement even if $\{a_n\}$ is not bounded as mentioned.